# Wrap raw queries in a transaction

Tags: .net, oracle, entity-framework-core

I must do these 3 operations in sequence over a database:

1. Truncate final table
2. Migrate data from start table to final table
3. Truncate start table

I want to wrap these operations in a single transaction, because i want to execute a rollback if anything goes wrong.

I did something like the following:

```
using(var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    try {
        await _context.Database.ExecuteRawQueryAsync("truncate...");
        await _context.Database.ExecuteRawQueryAsync("insert into ... select from ...");
        await _context.Database.ExecuteRawQueryAsync("truncate...");

        await transaction.CommitAsync();
    }
    catch(...) {
        await transaction.RollBackAsync();
    }
}
```

I think that this isn't the right way to do this because i can see that db tables get modified before the code reaches the commit line.
I even tried to execute the first truncate, launch a new exception and execute the rollback but data didn't get restored.

Ps: i can't use stored procedures.

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: That code looks fine.  What RDBMS is it?  Some don't support transactional DDL.

Comment: It's Oracle, i forgot to mention It.

Comment: Oracle does not support transactions with DDL.  Oracle will commit after each Truncate.  You might use DELETE instead.

Comment: What is `ExecuteRawQueryAsync` ? EF Core has no such method. EF Core doesn't change how the underlying ADO.NET works either. You have to pass the DbTransaction instance to any DbCommand that needs to execute under a transaction, or use a TransactionScope. Using EF Core makes it *harder* to execute raw SQL anyway. It's not needed for such cases

Comment: In fact, googling for `ExecuteRawQueryAsync` returns only this hit, which means this is your own custom method. We can't tell why your own custom code isn't working. I'd use Dapper to execute SQL without the normal ADO.NET boilerplate.

Comment: On the other hand, EF Core's [ExecuteSqlRawAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlrawasync?view=efcore-6.0) will work fine with the transaction started by `Database.BeginTransaction`. As the docs explain, `To use this method with a transaction, first call BeginTransaction(DatabaseFacade, IsolationLevel) or UseTransaction.`